# Rotate 3d Model as you move your bones in Threejs

Tags: three.js, skinning, 3d-model

Basically I am working with Rigged 3D Model imported from Blender. I want to map my Posenet cords with model's bone so as I move my arm, model's arm is also moved similarly.

**I am able to access the bones and map them to posenet cords but cant find a way to sync the movement.**

These are the bones accessed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSOIf.png)

This is how I have mapped. And there seem to be no error in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhaBW.png)